# Probability of picking $n$ a palindrome

Tags: probability, word-problem, palindrome

I am struggling to see how to solve this question.

[image]

My confusion stems from the *Less probable*, for n plain drones the equation I derived was $9\times10^{\frac{n+1}{2}-1}$ this is under the assumption that the plaindrone dose not start with a zero. So I set up the equation to see if I could get a feeling, but still not sure.

$$\frac{9 \times 10^{\frac{n+1}{2}-1}}{n}<6.7\times10^{-20} $$

So I thought of a dice and the say the probability of rolling a $1$ $p=\frac{1}{6}$ is less probable that rolling a $2$ $3$ or a $4$ for $p=\frac{3}{6}$. But this still didn't really give me any insight to this question. Just wondering if someone could expand what less probable means in this context.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this notation:

$$x=10^na_n+10^{n-1}a_{n-1}+...+10a_1+a_0=\overline{a_na_{n-1}...a_1a_0}$$

A number of $n$ digits is palyindromic if and only if $$a_{n-k}=a_k 
 \ \ \forall k<n$$

This means that we have to choose $\lceil{\frac n2}\rceil$ ciphers(the others one are forced). All of this ciphers can vary between $0$ and $9$ except for $a_n\neq 0$ so:

$$ 9\times 10^{\lceil{\frac n2}\rceil-1}$$

That can be rewritten as:

$$9\times 10^{\frac n2 -1} \ \ \ \text{if} \ \  n \ \ \text{is even}$$
$$9\times 10^{\frac {n+1}{2} -1} \ \ \ \text{if} \ \  n \ \ \text{is odd}$$

Clearly all of the possible numbers of $n$ digits are $9\times 10^{n-1}$  so our probability will be(dividing good cases by possible cases):

$$10^{-\frac n2 } \ \ \ \text{if} \ \  n \ \ \text{is even}$$
$$ 10^{\frac {1-n}{2} } \ \ \ \text{if} \ \  n \ \ \text{is odd}$$

Formally we should do $2$ disequations. Indicating with $p$ the probabily of the neutrino. If $n$ is even:

$$10^{-\frac n2 }<p$$
$$-\frac n2 <\log_{10}(p)$$
$$n>-2\log_{10}(p)$$
$$n>\log_{10}(\frac{1}{p^2})$$
$$n>38.34$$
$$n\geq 40$$

If $n$ is odd :

$$10^{\frac 12-\frac n2 }<p$$
$$\frac 12-\frac n2  <\log_{10}(p)$$
$$n>1-2\log_{10}(p)$$
$$n>1+\log_{10}(\frac{1}{p^2})$$
$$n>39.34$$
$$n\geq 41$$

So $n=40$ is enough :).

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you. When the question said 'n' palidrones I throught it ment n numbers as the sample space. Now I see Thank You.